# Question about Kotlin Coroutine Cancellation

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

I have a code something like the following in my app

```
class MyFragment : Fragment(), CoroutineScope by MainScope() {
    
    override fun onDestroy() {
        cancel()
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        doSomething()
    }

    private fun doSomething() = launch {
        val data = withContext(Dispathers.IO) {
            getData()
        }

        val pref = context!!.getSharedPreferences("mypref", MODE_PRIVATE)
        pref.edit().putBoolean("done", true).apply()
    }
}
```

In production, I get many NPEs in doSomething() while accessing context.

My assumption was that the coroutine gets cancelled after calling cancel() in onDestroy(), so I didn't bother to check the context for null value. But it looks like coroutine continues to execute even after cancel() is called. I think it happens if the cancel() is called after completing the withContext and before resuming the coroutine.

So I replaced doSomething() with following.

```
    private fun doSomething() = launch {
        val data = withContext(Dispathers.IO) {
            getData()
        }

        if (isActive) {
            val pref = context!!.getSharedPreferences("mypref", MODE_PRIVATE)
            pref.edit().putBoolean("done", true).apply()
        }
    }
```

This fixes the crash.

However, Is this an expected behaviour or am I doing something wrong? Kotlin documentation aren't very clear about this. And most of the examples online are like my original code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code assumes that the `withContext()` will stop execution when it returns, if the scope is cancelled, but actually it didn't, till version [1.3.0](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/releases/tag/1.3.0) of kotlin coroutines. Here is GitHub [issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/pull/1192). I guess that you are using an earlier version of the library.

I also recommend you use [LifecycleScope](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope) instead of a custom scope. It's part of `lifecycle-runtime-ktx` library. So, simplified solution looks like:

```
// build.gradle
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0-rc02"
}
```

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        doSomething()
    }

    private fun doSomething() = viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        val data = withContext(Dispathers.IO) {
            getData()
        }

        val pref = context!!.getSharedPreferences("mypref", MODE_PRIVATE)
        pref.edit().putBoolean("done", true).apply()
    }
}
```

There are other helpful utilities which simplifies coroutines usage, take a look at [Use Kotlin coroutines with Architecture components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines) documentation section.

Comment: Thanks. My codebase is quite large and transitioning into ViewModel isn't practical at this point. I will look into the LifecycleScope.  Even with LifecycleScope isn't there a possibility that a cancelled coroutine continues after withContext. Especially if it is cancelled after the completion of withContext and before resuming the coroutine?

Comment: @adarsha It's save to access the `context` after `withContext()` completion, because all builders like`'withContext` checks cancellation status on exit, so if the next line of code is executed, the coroutine isn't cancelled and it means that the fragment is active. Look at [Suspend Lifecycle-aware coroutines](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#suspend) example, there is the same behavior is explained in the comments.

Comment: It doesn't explain 2 things - why context is null and why isActive check fixes the issue

Comment: @adarsha Indeed, I suggested that the reason is a custom scope implementation, but now I see that your implementation looks correctly too. I found out that `withContext` implementation was updated not long ago, and It didn't check the cancellation before that. I've updated the answer with more details.

Comment: Thanks. I was indeed using the older version. Will update to 1.3.0.

Comment: @ValeriyKatkov What's the trade-off between viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope and lifecycleScope ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour since Coroutine Cancellation is cooperative in nature.

See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#cancellation-is-cooperative

While suspend functions will check for the state of coroutine in your case you will have to do this yourself.

A cleaner way is to have these operations in a viewmodel and just cancel the coroutine in ViewModel `onCleared`; if you are using ViewModel

Comment: It just moves the cancellation to a different point in the lifecycle. But still I can't avoid isActive check if indeed a coroutine can run after cancellation.

Comment: The greater problem in your code is u are coupling shared pref editing with the lifecycle of the Fragment.
If you need that then ViewModel should communicate it to fragment, which it cant do after `onCleared` call.
If you dont need that run the shared pref edit with applicationContext.
If you are following some architecture then I can almost say this piece of code violates Single responsibility principle.

Comment: Coroutines cant just stop after invoking `cancel`. If it was designed that way it would run into the same problem faced by Java's `Thread.stop()`

Comment: It is a simple code to illustrate the issue. As Valeriy Katkov pointed out it turned out that I was using older version.

Answer (score 0):

The latest coroutine updates have introduced the possibility of working safe with scopes. Basically if you are doing async work in Fragments or Activities you use `lifecycleScope` and if you are going async work in ViewModel you need to use `viewModelScope`. There is also a GlobalScope that can be used in any class but it was proved to have many stability flaws and should be avoided. In any case scenario you should use either lifecycleScope or viewModelScope and use suspend functions in other classes.

So here is the way to do it:

```
 override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        doSomething()
    }
 }

 private suspend fun doSomething(){
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
        getData()
        if (isActive) {
            val pref = context!!.getSharedPreferences("mypref", MODE_PRIVATE)
            pref.edit().putBoolean("done", true).apply()
        }
    }
 }
```

As you can see in the code above, there is no need for a scope or launch in the doSomething function because that acts as a task that gets executed in the already launched coroutine above in onActivityCreated. Launching a new coroutine in the doSomething() function is pointless. Also, you can encapsulate your entire code in your withContext() statement because getting shared preferences is also a transaction that works best on Dispatchers.IO. Alternatively you can change the context to the desired context anytime you want, like:

```
   withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
        getData()
        if (isActive) {
            val pref = context!!.getSharedPreferences("mypref", MODE_PRIVATE)
            pref.edit().putBoolean("done", true).apply()
        }
        withContext(Dispatchers.Default){
            // Heavy computing
        }
    }
```

Always remember that Dispatchers.IO is optimised best for database transactions, shared preferences and networking calls. If you do heavy computing like forEach in forEach and stuff like that, use Dispatchers.Default and if you need to do view work, use Dispatchers.Main.

These scopes make sure your task gets executed without interruption from other activity components, and if it is interrupted by something like activity destruction, it prevents exceptions and uses garbage collector properly on everything that's inside the scope. Since I started using the scopes, there were no more crashes for me.

Comment: I don't think it is safe to access context from IO thread?. In case of Fragment context!! is actually actually getContext().

Comment: Not at all, because here you use the context only to retrieve some information from the sharedPrefs. The coroutines know how to use context safely and drop it once it becomes dangerous (if it becomes, but definitely not on IO operations). Also, it is recommended to use requireContext() instead of getContext().